# Getting the following error: "SequelizeDatabaseError column "createdAt" does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, express, sequelize.js, passport.js

I've been going through [this tutorial](http://anneblankert.blogspot.in/2015/06/node-authentication-migrate-from.html) and the [github repository](https://github.com/anneb/easy-node-authentication) for creating an express/passport/sequelize authorization using a Postgres database. I know what the issue is, I just need help with a solution.

After having everything in place and creating database, I try to login, but I keep getting the error:

> "SequelizeDatabaseError" column "createdAt" does not exist".

There appears to be a bug where Sequelize 3.X.X is not able to read `createdAt` and the database I set up will automatically lowercase all tables created.

I believe there is a way to fix the `createdAt` requirement to be lowercase, but I can't seem to locate it at all. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue?

Comment: PostgreSQL folds identifiers (such as table and column names) to lower case unless you double quote them. So how did you create the `createdAt` column? Did you double quote it? How are you accessing this column? Are you double quoting it there?

Comment: @muistooshort I created the [createdAt:tagname] using the command: 

'ALTER TABLE add users Add createAt timestamp;'

I didn't know if you could allow camelcase using quotes, I'll give it a try.

Comment: If you need it to be case sensitive then double quote it: `alter table users add "createdAt" timestamp`.

Answer (score 10):

if you can't seem to fix the column name to `createdAt` then you can just add an extra field to the sequelize config

```
var config = {
"define": {
    "createdAt": "createdat",
    "updatedAt": "updatedat"
  } /*don't forget to add host, port, dialect, etc.*/
}
var sequelize = new Sequelize(database, username, password, config);
```

Answer (score 9):

if you dont want to take the time you should do:

```js
var config = {
"define": {
    whatever: req.body.whatever,
    ...
  } ,{
    timestamps: false
}
}
```

with timestamps false you are not taking the time, that might be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by adding this to the sequelize config

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
....

define: {
underscored: true,
createdAt: 'created_at',
updatedAt: 'updated_at',
}
});
```

create created-at, updated-at in migration like this :

```
  created_at: {
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
    allowNull: false,
    
   },
   updated_at: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.DATE,
   },
```

then make sure to add field name mapping in your models files :

```
 createdAt: {
  type: DataTypes.DATE,
  field: 'created_at'
 },

updatedAt: {
  type: DataTypes.DATE,
  field: 'updated_at'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, adding "underscored":true to the config file solved the problem.

```
    "development":
          {"host": "localhost",
           "dialect": "postgres",
           "quoteIdentifiers":false,
            "underscored":true }
```

Comment: Can you clarify/correct your post, please: Is the keyword `underscore` or `underscored`?

Comment: Sorry for that, it is underscored.

Comment: you need pass false to the underscored, its a boolean